# Name for class which both reads and writes

Tags: .net, oop

I have two classes now: `EventsReader` and `EventsWriter`. They actually work with one class and share some common functionality. I want to combine them into one class but can't choose a good name for this class. The only idea I have is `EventsProvider` but isn't Provider more about reading than writing?

What name would you use for class which combines operations of Reading and Writing?

Comment: `EventsManager`, `EventsController`, `EventsStore`...

Comment: sounds like a _possible_ SRP violation.. having trouble naming a class can be a flag that SRP is being violated

Comment: @csturtz, I thought about it... but in this case this combination looks very reasonable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, as to the name, I would lean towards EventsIO or something along those lines. Or, as Adriano suggested, you could concatenate the two together and make it ReaderWriter. However, this is not as important to me as what you are describing that you want to do...

**My Real Advice**

I would suggest really looking at what the common functionality is. Without seeing your code I cannot say this with 100% certainty, but it seems like you should be using [Composition over Inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), or in your case composition over combination. You could keep your EventsReader and EventsWriter as separate classes that consume a class that deals with the common functionality.

Take a look at the [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29). Especially, the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). If you combine the classes, then reading changes, but writing does not, then you have to make a code change for a class that deals with both, when you only want to change the functionality of one piece. Basically, you will have more than one reason for change.

Ultimately, you need to make your code work well, but I am suggesting that you really take a look at what combining might do for future maintainability versus having the two classes that consume a new class that encapsulates the common functionality. Only you will know your code base well enough to make that decision. As @csturtz commented, having trouble naming objects is a smell that you are indeed violating the SRP.

Answer (score 1):

In the framework we find `System.Threading.ReaderWriterLock` so...why not `EventsReaderWriter`?

Answer (score 0):

sounds a bit like a [domain-driven design service](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/08/21/services-in-domain-driven-design/), so what about EventsService ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the code-smell "Manager". Mostly I don´t like it but you can do whatever you want in the class. .NET uses that for ConfigurationManager and not ConfigurationReaderWriter.